# Why isn't the Eclipse GCov plugin providing percentage numbers?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcov

I have the system defined below, freshly set up.
In the unit test build (with debug information) I have enabled gcov output by providing the compile flags "-g -pg --coverage" and link flags "-pg --coverage -lgcov".

The source code is organized as follows:

```
/
   /src
      MyClass1.cpp
      MyClass1.hpp
      ...
   /test
      MyClass1Test.cpp
      ...
```

When I execute the unit tests, .gcno and .gcna files are generated (in sub-directories beneath src/ and test/).
For the most part, the gcov plugin reads these files correctly.
When I double-click a typical .gcna file, it shows all visited files,  with the "Total Lines", "Instrumented Lines" and "Executed Lines" columns filled out correctly (from what I can tell). Double clicking on the file names, the editor is launched with correct coloring of the line non/visited lines.

The only thing missing is the results of the entire "Coverage %" (the thing I'm actually looking for) column, it's empty. I cannot obtain information on what the coverage is, not on file level, nor on function level.

I have double-checked that g++ is instructed to emit debug output (-g is supplied to the compiler), since I'm suspecting that the .gcov information generated is not entirely correct.

If I open MyClass1.cpp.gcov, it looks like this:

```
   -:    0:Source:src/MyClass1.cpp
    -:    0:Programs:4
    -:    1:/*EOF*/
    -:    2:/*EOF*/
    -:    3:/*EOF*/
    -:    4:/*EOF*/
    -:    5:/*EOF*/
    -:    6:/*EOF*/
    -:    7:/*EOF*/
    -:    8:/*EOF*/
    -:    9:/*EOF*/
    -:   10:/*EOF*/
    -:   11:/*EOF*/
    -:   12:/*EOF*/
    -:   13:/*EOF*/
    -:   14:/*EOF*/
    -:   15:/*EOF*/
    -:   16:/*EOF*/
    -:   17:/*EOF*/
    -:   18:/*EOF*/
    -:   19:/*EOF*/
#####:   20:/*EOF*/
    -:   21:/*EOF*/
#####:   22:/*EOF*/
#####:   23:/*EOF*/
#####:   24:/*EOF*/
#####:   25:/*EOF*/
#####:   26:/*EOF*/
#####:   27:/*EOF*/
#####:   28:/*EOF*/
#####:   29:/*EOF*/
#####:   30:/*EOF*/
#####:   31:/*EOF*/
#####:   32:/*EOF*/
#####:   33:/*EOF*/
#####:   34:/*EOF*/
#####:   35:/*EOF*/
#####:   36:/*EOF*/
#####:   37:/*EOF*/
#####:   38:/*EOF*/
#####:   39:/*EOF*/
#####:   40:/*EOF*/
#####:   41:/*EOF*/
    -:   42:/*EOF*/
    -:   43:/*EOF*/
    8:   44:/*EOF*/
    -:   45:/*EOF*/
    8:   46:/*EOF*/
    -:   47:/*EOF*/
```

(and so on)

This doesn't look right to me, I suspect that gcov cannot find the  source code. However, does that really matter? The line numbers are there, and gcov should be able to compute the last column by performing a division between the columns "Executed Lines" and "Instrumented Lines".

Does anybody have any idea what's going on here?

Any help much appreciated.

System details:

- i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz, 16 GB RAM
- Windows 7, running VirtualBox 5.0.0
- VirtualBox (on 4 cores and 7 GB RAM, with guest additions installed) running Kubuntu 14.10
- Kubuntu running 14.10.Eclipse C/C++, rev. Mars (4.5.0)
- Plugins: C/C++ multi-core visualizer, C/C++ unit testing support, MyLyn for Jenkins and Gerrit
- gcov (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1
- Build system: CMake generating "Eclipse CDT - Ninja" project.
- Ninja: 1.6.0.git
- g++ (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1
- Source code: C++11
- Test library: boost 1.55.0

Comment: I now have it working. AFAICT, I have changed two things:

Comment: This seems to be an issue with window managers. When using TDE (trinity desktop), Eclipse won't show the figures, but when using Xfce, it does.